# Convert from Protocol buffer to heirachical Generic Request

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

We are planning to move grpc micro architecture. So we need a general adapter for converting protocol buffer Request object to existing POJO object vice versa.

In our current scenario, We have :-

```
 message RequestIdentity {
        Tenant tenant = 1;
        string userToken = 2;
        string ipAddress = 3;
    }

message StudentRequest {
     RequestIdentity requestIdentity = 1;
     string id = 2;
     string name = 3;
    }
```

As above scenario, we have to convert into our generic `ServiceRequest<Student>` POJO object . Protocol buffer object has two part:

1. RequestIdentity -  is responsible for creating ServiceRequest.
2. id and name     - are payload of Student.

like wise convert different request using general adapter ? any idea

Comment: Alas there is no generic way to convert from Protobufs to POJOs.   As mentioned in the protobuf guide, they don't make for good general purpose objects, and are instead for storage and transmission.

Comment: It is true ... it is not supported inheritance or generic . so we wrote general mapper to convert proto buffer object to our POJO object.